# How to run web IRC Client in node-webkit on Windows?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, thelounge

I am trying to run a web IRC client, [The Lounge](https://github.com/thelounge/lounge/), as a regular Windows IRC Client.

But after packing into a `.nw` file, it does not work:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/thelounge/lounge.git
cd lounge
npm install
NODE_ENV=production npm run build
zip -r ../lounge.zip *
mv lounge.zip to lounge.nw
```

and then on Windows:

```sh
copy /b nw.exe+app.nw app.exe
```

Comment: What does not work exactly? Do you have an error message to share, by any chance?

Comment: Also, note that The Lounge is a server + client combo, not only a client. You need to install and run the server, then access the client through your browser (or make the client a launchable app depending on your browser). Usually, it's meant to be hosted on a server that runs 24/7, and then you access it from your laptop through your browser. Hope that helps!